# NodeJS w/ MongoDb: Removing a sub-field in a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON object stored in a collection like this:

```
[
    {
        "username":"j",
        "pass":"t",
        "tracking":
        {
            "bettercallsaul":["1x1","1x2","1x3"]
        }
     }
]
```

I'm wanting to delete the field "bettercallsaul" inside the "tracking" field.

I've tried running a line along such as this:

`collection.updateOne({ "username" : req.session.username }, { $unset : { "tracking" : { showname : 1 } } });`

And it has only managed to delete the entire tracking entry rather than just the bettercallsaul entry. Is it possible to delete this subfield?

edit: Forgot to mention how my expected output should look:

`[
        {
            "username":"j",
            "pass":"t",
            "tracking": {}
         }
    ]`

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Comment: Updated my question with the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `$set` and setting empty object:

```
db.collection.updateOne({ "username" : req.session.username }, { $set : { "tracking" : { } } });
```

Alternatively you can use the dot notation to remove only one subfield:

```
db.collection.updateOne({ "username" : req.session.username }, { $unset : { "tracking.bettercallsaul" : 1 } });
```

Comment: Got this to work after looking up more info about dot notation. Now I have some other bugs to fix. Thanks!